# Control CSS color for windowtext in FireFox?

Tags: css, firefox, colors

I use a KDE theme with dark menus and white text. In Firefox (5.0), under Preferences->Content->Colors I have black text and a white background chosen. I have "use system colors" unchecked.

I encountered a site that specifies their CSS to set color: windowtext, but hardcodes the background to white. This results in white text on a white background. I don't understand why Firefox is using white text for windowtext.

How can I force Firefox to use a color of my choice when it resolves "windowtext"? Is there something I can put in userContent.css or userChrome.css? or some other way?

Comment: What a strange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tell Firefox to pick an arbitrary color to resolve to when encountering a system color. That's hardcoded into the rendering engine. However, you can still tell it to set the text black and the background white for that site.

Go to `userContent.css` and add the following style:

```
@-moz-document domain('offendingsite.com') {
    body {
        color: black !important;
        background-color: white !important;
    }
}
```

Then restart Firefox and visit the site again.

Of course, `offendingsite.com` should be replaced with the domain name of the site in question.

Comment: This works, but there's two things I don't like about it: first, it requires me to solve it for every site I encounter whose CSS doesn't work for light-on-dark system themes, and second, once I put !important in, I take control away from the web site designer. I want them to be able to use colors of their choosing. I just don't want them to be able to mix those with colors of MY choosing (windowtext), especially because it sounds like I can't actually do the choosing at the browser level.

Comment: @bwtaylor: Well, that's likely why the CSS3 Color Module deprecated system colors.

Comment: Hooray for that. It seems like a Firefox bug to use the system color when I unchecked "use system colors". In the particular site, they use color: windowtext to color links, so I modified your recommendation and changed "body" to "a" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

well if you can get access to a user css file, you can set

```
body
{
  color: black !important
  background-color: white !important
}
```

I think that's the closest you can get with it though.